# Setting consider_all_requests_local temporarily for rspec testing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have some custom 404 and 500 pages I want to test, but I need Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local to be false for feature testing temporarily, and then turn it back on after the test is complete so that other tests can see the stack trace if they fail during testing. Is there any way of doing so or is there possibly another solution to achieve what I'm looking for?

For reference I am using Capybara and selenium-chrome to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and the reset `consider_all_requests_local` in before/after blocks:

```
describe 'my awesome test' do
  before do
    Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  end

  after do
    Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  end

  it 'does something magical' do
    # some tests
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that unless this test is ran first, it doesn't work down the line because I cant change the config settings after initialization.

Comment: I'm able to set consider_all_requests_local just like this and can confirm that it can be reset after initialization.  It also doesn't matter what order the tests are run in.

Comment: Would it make any difference if I'm using Capybara for testing and selenium-chrome? Because I'm doing something similar to that and it doesn't seem to work out...

Comment: Ah, yes, that could do it. Selenium is probably firing up a new backend in a thread separate from your test code.

Comment: Is there any way to tell Selenium to fire a new backend for just these two tests from the updated test code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of any way to do it. Hopefully someone else will chime in with an answer that will work with Selenium.